# Optimal transport with relaxed constraint on marginals

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, optimization, constraints, optimal-transport

Let $X$ be some appropriate space (metric measure, Polish, whatever...) and $X\times X$ the product space with $\pi^1$ and $\pi^2$ as projections onto the first and second factor, respectively. Let $\mu$ and $\nu$  be two probability measures (again some appropriate space).

The Kantorovich formulation of optimal transport of measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ seeks a minimizer of
\begin{equation}
\Pi\mapsto\int c(x,y)\;d\Pi(x,y)
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\pi^1_*\Pi&=\mu\\
\pi^2_*\Pi&=\nu
\end{array}\qquad\qquad \qquad (\#)
\end{equation}
I thought about it for a bit and in my context a different constraint makes more sense, namely:
\begin{equation}
\pi^1_*\Pi-\pi^2_*\Pi=\mu-\nu\;.\qquad\qquad \qquad (\dagger)
\end{equation}
I remember having seen this constraint somewhere, too.

**Question:** Since ($\dagger$) is more general I wonder what the advantages are. Which properties does $(\mu,\nu)\mapsto \min_{\Pi\in(\dagger)}\int c(x,y)\;d\Pi(x,y)$ have that $(\mu,\nu)\mapsto \min_{\Pi\in(\#)}\int c(x,y)\;d\Pi(x,y)$  doesn't have. I also can't find the reference anymore. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear to me what the operation "$-$" means in $\pi_*^1\Pi - \pi_*^2\Pi$, could you please clarify?

Comment: good point. I guess it should be defined via its action on test functions.

Comment: so for any measurable test function $f:X\to \mathbb R$, smooth with compact support, we should have $\Pi(f\circ \pi^1)-\Pi(f\circ \pi^2)=\mu(f)-\nu(f)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you suggested $(\dagger)$ is a minimization problem over a bigger set of probability measures that in the original problem (#). I don't think it is accurate to state that it is more general, since solving your problem $(\dagger)$ does not necessarily gives solution to the original one (#), and this problem $(\dagger)$ may have no advantages over the original problem (#).

Two comments about your problem $(\dagger)$:

1. It is possible to prove that the dual problem to yours is
   $$\sup_{f(x)-f(y)\leq c(x,y)}\int_{X}f(x)\mathrm{d}\mu-\int_{X}f(x)\mathrm{d}\nu$$
2. If $c$ is the metric of the space, then the two problems ((#) and $(\dagger)$) coincide, since the original problem (#) is known to be dependend only on the difference $\mu-\nu$ in this case. See [Wasserstein metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric).

Edit: The problem you suggested $(\dagger)$ is called "Kantorovich-Rubinstein transshipment problem". Reference can be found in "Mass Transportation Problems" Vol. I & II by Rachev and Ruschendorf.

Comment: Thanks MOMO.  That's right. Since the set of couplings that satisfy $(\dagger)$  contains the set of couplings that satify $(\#)$, it follows that a solution under the $(\dagger)$  contrain might not satisfy $(\#)$ at all. And a solution w.r.t $(\#)$ might not be a minimizer in $(\dagger)$. I think that the condition $(\dagger)$ has huge advantages, because it says that the deficit in the masses needs to be compensated by the transport.

Thanks a lot for the two comments. I'd love to know how you show that this is the dual. Im not good in these calculations.  
Thanks a lot also for the ref.

Comment: In short, one way pf proving it is to define the dual problem as a sublinear functional acting on $c$ and then using the Hahn-Banach theorem (there are of course many more details to consider to get a complete proof). You can also find this kind of duality theorems in the reference, although its terminology is quite different so it might be hard to follow.