# Optimal transport with relaxed constraint on terminal distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, constraints, optimal-transport

I have read the topic on relaxing constraint on relaxing marginal constraints [Optimal transport with relaxed constraint on marginals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170256/optimal-transport-with-relaxed-constraint-on-marginals), where the constraint is expressed as the difference of initial and final distribution.

**Question:** I wonder if there exists a problem: instead of using
 \begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\pi^1_*\Pi&=\mu\\
\pi^2_*\Pi&=\nu
\end{array}\qquad\qquad \qquad (\#)
\end{equation}, the marginals are changed to
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{c}
\pi^1_*\Pi&=\mu\\
\pi^2_*\Pi&\simeq\nu
\end{array}\qquad\qquad \qquad (\ast)
\end{equation}, where '$\simeq$' means that two distributions are similar, say if $\nu \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ while $\pi^2_*\Pi \sim \mathcal{N}(2,1)$ (mean has changed) or $\pi^2_*\Pi \sim \mathcal{N}(2,4)$ (both mean and variance have changed). Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the constraints by taking the the first marginal to be some given $\mu$ and the second marginal to be in some subset of distributions (in your case this subset should be all distribution "similar" to a given distribution $\nu$, however you wish to define this "similarity").

You can view this problem as a minimum over many optimal transport problems, where the minimum is taken over all distributions "similar" $\nu$.

More formally:

Let $Nu$ to be a set of distributions, then

$$\min\{\int c\ \mathrm{d}\Pi;\ \pi_*^1 \Pi=\mu,\ \pi_*^2 \Pi\in Nu\}=\min_{\nu'\in Nu}\min\{\int c\ \mathrm{d}\Pi;\ \pi_*^1 \Pi=\mu,\ \pi_*^2 \Pi=\nu'\}$$

If the subset $Nu$ is weak* compact and $c$ is lower semi-continuous then you know the minimum is attained for some $\nu'\in Nu$.

Comment: Thanks, MOMO. I have noticed that the original OPT is an LP problem and is convex in initial and final distributions. I think the problem you formulated is quite general and may be difficult to handle. How to solve this or is there any reference I can check? Thanks~

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with a relevant reference. A way to solve such a problem is, as I suggested  above, by solving the original problem for each similar distribution.